# Passing more than 16 kernel arguments in Alea.GPU

Tags: c#, .net, gpu, aleagpu

I have a fairly complex kernel that I am trying to write. As it turns out, I need to pass more than 16 arguments, and apparently Alea GPU has a limitation for 16 arguments. (http://quantalea.com/static/app/manual/reference/alea_cuda_il/alea-cuda-il-ilgpumodule.html)

I know that 16 arguments sounds like a bad idea to begin with... What other options are there? In normal code, I would of course wrap the things into it's own class, but what can I do in GPU code?

Comment: Can you pass an array or list?

Comment: you pass `deviceptr<T>`s for vector data, but here it was about passing different things, e.g. 2 numbers, 3 arrays, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can retrieve an untyped kernel object through `GPUModule.GPUEntities` property, then put those arguments into an list of `Object` type, then you can launch it.

You can also make some extension methods for that purpose and make them to be type safe, here is an example which I use only 3 arguments for simplicity:

```
public static class GPUModuleExtensions
{
    public static void MyGPULaunch<T1, T2, T3>(
        this ILGPUModule module,
        Action<T1, T2, T3> kernelD, LaunchParam lp,
        T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        // get the kernel object by method name
        var kernel = module.GPUEntities.GetKernel(kernelD.Method.Name).Kernel;
        // create parameter list (which is FSharpList)
        var parameterArray = new object[] {arg1, arg2, arg3};
        var parameterList = ListModule.OfArray(parameterArray);
        // use untyped LaunchRaw to launch the kernel
        kernel.LaunchRaw(lp, parameterList);
    }
}

public class GPUModule : ILGPUModule
{
    public GPUModule() : base(GPUModuleTarget.DefaultWorker)
    {
    }

    [Kernel]
    public void Kernel(deviceptr<int> outputs, int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        var tid = threadIdx.x;
        outputs[tid] = arg1 + arg2;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        const int n = 32;
        var lp = new LaunchParam(1, n);
        using (var outputs = GPUWorker.Malloc<int>(n))
        {
            this.MyGPULaunch(Kernel, lp, outputs.Ptr, 1, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (outputs.Gather())[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, in this example, I use `Action<T1,T2,T3>`, but `Action` type has maximum 16 types, so you might need to define your own delegate to pass more than 16 argument types.